# FreeRTOS suspend task from another function

Tags: multithreading, arduino, freertos, arduino-due

So I have a half duplex bus driver, where I send something and then always have to wait a lot of time to get a response. During this wait time I want the processor to do something valuable, so I'm thinking about using FreeRTOS and vTaskDelay() or something.

One way to do it would off be splitting the driver up in some send/receive part. After sending, it returns to the caller. The caller then suspends, and does the reception part after a certain period of time.

But, the level of abstraction would be finer if it continues to be one task from the user point of view, as today. Therefore I was thinking, is it possible for a function within a task to suspend the task itself? Like

```
 void someTask()
 {
     while(true){
       someFunction(&someTask(), arg 1, arg 2,...);
       otherStuff(); 
 }


 }

 void someFunction(*someSortOfReferenceToWhateverTaskWhoCalled, arg1, arg2 ...)
 {
    if(something)  
    {

       /*Use the pointer or whatever to suspend the task that called this                      function*/
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the FreeRTOS API reference for vTaskSuspend, http://www.freertos.org/a00130.html

However I am not sure you are going about controlling the flow of the program in the correct way. Tasks can be suspended on queues, events, delays etc.

For example in serial comms, you might have a task that feeds data into a queue (but suspends if it is full) and an interrupt that takes data out of the queue and transmits the data, or an interrupt putting data in a queue, or sending an event to a task to say there is data ready for it to process, the task can then wake up and process the data or take it out of the queue.

One thing I think is important though (in my opinion) is to only have one suspend point in any task. This is not a strict rule, but will make your life a lot easier in most situations.

There a numerous other task control mechanisms that are common to most RTOS's.

Have a good look around the FreeRTOS website and play with a few demo's. There is also plenty of generic RTOS tutorials on the web. It it worth learning how use the basic features of most RTOS's. It is actually not that complicated.

Comment: Yeah I was browsing past that suspend command too, however as I would like too suspend for a certain period of time and not indefinitely it doesn't work straight off. 

My latest idea is to extend the com. bus driver (in this case modbus driver) with a default argument. If the caller uses the default argument true, the function will return a delay time when waiting for a response. Then this delay time could be perhaps be used directly by the caller in vTaskDelay() or something.

Comment: Playing around some, it seems like vTaskDelay() can be called from within someFunction(), and RTOS will automatically keep track of which task called someFunction() so no need to send a handle. Neat. Makes sense actually, as there is always only one task at once running, RTOS will know which task to suspend. 

Now this makes stuff simpler. Now I can basically replace all the Arduino delay() with vTaskDelay() for the bus driver I guess.

Comment: Yes you could do that. I still think you would be better off having some kind of event driven system, rather than just waiting for a period of time. You should know when your your serial (or ethernet) driver has received a response from the modbus. (I have work with modbus quite extensively in the past)